# How to Improve my HTML Code and trigger python onclick of button in Php

Tags: python, php, html

```
<?php
    // $command=escapeshellcmd("D:\Wamp64\www\demo.py");
    // $output=shell_exec($command);
    // echo $output;
?>
<html>
<head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><title>File Arrangement Portal</title>
<style>
/* .div2 {
  width: 400px;
  background-color:black;
  height: 100px;  
  padding: 250px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:60%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%)
}
p2{
    background-color: grey;
    left:100px;
    top:100px:
} */
.button1{
  background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
  position:absolute;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 22px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  top:195%;
  left:30%
}
.button2{
  background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
  position:absolute;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 22px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  top:210%;
  left:33%
}
.button3{
  background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
  position:absolute;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 22px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  top:210%;
  left:32%
}
.button4{
  background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
  position:absolute;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 22px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  top:220%;
  left:31%
}
.button5{
  background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
  position:absolute;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 22px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  top:190%;
  left:31%
}
.button6{
  background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
  position:absolute;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 22px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  top:190%;
  left:31%
}
.hello{
    color:grey;
    position:absolute;
    top:0.5%;
    left:32%;
}
.hello1{
    color:grey;
    position:absolute;
    top:17%;
    left:22%;
}
.hello2{
    color:grey;
    position:absolute;
    top:34%;
    left:32%;
}
.hello3{
    color:grey;
    position:absolute;
    top:51%;
    left:36%;
}
.hello4{
    color:grey;
    position:absolute;
    top:67%;
    left:35%;
}
.hello5{
    color:grey;
    position:absolute;
    top:83%;
    left:35%;
}
    body {background-color: #5C5858;}
    h1 {color: black;}
    /* p {color: blue;} */
    .rectangle {
  height: 40px;
  width: device-widthpx;
  background-color: black;
}
  </style></head>
<body>
<div class="rectangle"><h1 style="font-family:Times New Roman;text-align:center";><font color="white">File Arrangement Portal</font></h1></div>
<div style="position: absolute;top:63%; left: 50%;padding:260px;transform:translate(-50%,-50%);width: 450px; height: 100px; background: black; border: 1px solid black">
<h2 class='hello'>To Arrange the  files and Run a Check<button class="button button1">Click Me!</button></h2>
<h2 class='hello1'>To Arrange the  files from root folder and Run a check again<button class="button button2">Click Me!</button></h2>
<h2 class='hello2'>To Creation of PPT and ZIP File<button class="button button3">Click Me!</button></h2>
<h2 class='hello3'>To Copy the Files<button class="button button4">Click Me!</button></h2>
<h2 class='hello4'>To Paste the Files<button class="button button5">Click Me!</button></h2>
<h2 class='hello5'>Run a QC for Single File<button class="button button6">Click Me!</button></h2>
</div>

<!-- <h1>This is a Heading</h1> -->
<!-- <div class="div2"><p2 style="left:120px; top:100px";><font color="white">Click on one of the text labels to toggle the related control:</font></p2></div> -->
<script> 
// console.log(<?php echo $output ?>);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am just now started Learning HTML with online support i create this UI, I know this is poor but i want to know how can i improve with lesser code and improve the looks as well. And how can i replace the existing ui with better organised code.

**I need help also like i want to trigger around 6 python code whenever user clicks respective six buttons.**

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will need a server to run your Python code, and you should study how to write HTML code, using something like flexbox to do the layout instead of absolute positioning. This question will get downvoted. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for details

Answer (score 0):

To run commands with PHP you should use escapeshellcmd("path to.py") and shell_exec() https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php

Just an example:
`echo shell_exec(escapeshellcmd("path to.py"));`

"echo .." outputs the result of the .py

In order to achieve this in few minutes you should wrap your buttons in a form (Use POST if you don't want show the parameters in the address bar) and give them a name="".
The action of the form can be empty, action="", so it will refresh the actual page.
Then at the top of the page you check if there's POST, with if($_POST){} and which button has been pressed, with if($_POST["name given to the button"]){}. This is just a raw example.
What you wanna achieve is quite advanced if you just started HTML so be aware! Good Luck.

Complete example:

```
<?php
if($_POST){
  if($_POST["button1"]){
   echo shell_exec(escapeshellcmd("path to.py"));
  }
}
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
  <button name="button1" class="button button1">Click Me!</button>
<form>
```